# Issue with deploying GWT app to tomcat in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, tomcat

Following [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/GWT/article.html), I could execute GWT app using eclipse. I could access the app at `http://127.0.0.1:8888/De_vogella_gwt_helloworld.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`.

[image]

[image]

Then, I googled to find a way to deploy the app to tomcat, and I found [this site](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/). It has two step way to exporting GWT app to tomcat.

1. Exporting the src directory into jar file.
2. Using ant create a war file.

I copied the `hello.war` file into `/Library/Tomcat/webapps`, and open the browser with `localhost:8080/hello` to get this error.

[image]

When I click the HTML file in webapps directory, so I think something's wrong with the packaging.

[image]

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile your GWT app to run in production mode. See [this section](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideProdMode) of the GWT doc for detailed steps (for GWT 2.4).

Answer (score 0):

From David's answer, I could get it working.

I had to compile the application again.

[image]

to get it working.

[image]